# VBA Issue #6 Overflow for tr value

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code, and every time I enter into the InputBox ".2" for the tax rate, I receive an overflow error, but I can't figure out why.

```
Sub bookNetPay()
    Dim en As String
    Dim tr As Single
 
    en = InputBox("What is the employee's name?")
    tr = InputBox("What is the tax rate?")
    
End Sub
```

I tried putting in error descriptions, changing the value of what I put into the box, putting "CDbl" in front of InputBox, but this hasn't solved any of my issues. I get the overflow error every time. I'm following a video my teacher did, and his code works, so I can't seem to see what is the difference between my code and his.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, but it would be better to use `Application.InputBox` here instead of `InputBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enter ,2?

```
Sub bookNetPay()
    Dim en As String
    Dim trTemp As String
    Dim tr As Single
 
    en = InputBox("What is the employee's name?")
    trTemp = InputBox("What is the tax rate?")

    If Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) = "." Then
        tr = CDbl(Replace(trTemp, ",", "."))
    Else
        tr = CDbl(Replace(trTemp, ".", ","))
    End If
    Debug.Print "tr = " & tr
End Sub
```